# Why does the girl need ox heart to give her favours to the ugly monk?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-name-of-the-rose

In [***The Name of the Rose***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091605/) (1986), Adso, the novice, found an ox heart & he informed his master William. William explains it...

> It is the heart of an ox. One of the monks probably gave it to that peasant girl in exchange for her favors.
>
> He must have been a very ugly monk.

Why does she specifically need an ox heart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not **specifically** an ox heart...it's just **anything** to eat.

The (translated) base novel explains

> **William** “Very well, but we can deduce who it was from many and certain clues. First of all, the man was old and ugly, one with whom a girl does not go willingly, especially if she is beautiful, as you say, though it seems to me, my dear wolf cub, that you were prepared to find any food delicious.”
>
> **Adso** “Why old and ugly?”
>
> **William** “Because the girl didn’t go with him for love, but for a pack of scraps. Certainly she is a girl from the village who, perhaps not for the first time, grants her favors to some lustful monk **so as to have something for her and her family to eat.**”
>
> <sup>The Name of the Rose - Umberto Eco</sup>

Comment: Maybe the ox heart is a bit more specific because of the "he must have been an old and ugly monk," meaning "that's a pretty prime/expensive/valuable piece of meat," so the price must have been high for her favors.